# AS3 Weird string split error

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, date

Why I'm getting this error? (Adobe Air)

ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property . not found on builtin.as$0.MethodClosure and there is no default value.

```
var srt:String = "2010.11.12 19:15";    
var _split:Array = str.split(" ");
var _date:String = _split[0];
var _time:String = _split[1];
var dateArr:Array = _date.split["."];
var timeArr:Array = _time.split[":"];
```

I just need to create a Date object from this string, like new Date(dateArr[0], dateArr[1]-1, dateArr[2], timeArr[0], timeArr[1]);

Answer (score 9):

`_date.split["."]` should be `_date.split(".")`. Same for the other line. By saying `_date.split["."]` you are attempting to look up a property called `.` on the `split` property of `_date`. As the `split` property is a function, it doesn't have a property `.`

Comment: ooooooouch, so stupid mistake:) it's hard to code at night:) thanks